# Cannot import database - "Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes" error

Tags: visual-studio, ssms, sql-server-data-tools

I created a new project in Visual Studio 2017 from SQL Server Database Project template. Then I tried to import an existing database. After defining a new connection (I used the browse tab; the connection was correctly set up because it showed me the list of all databases on my SQL Server), I got the error

```
Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
```

I also tried from SSMS (v17.9) to extract data-tier application so I can use the "Import Data-tier Application File" in Visual Studio, but this time SSMS gave me identical error message. I updated Visual Studio and SSDT to the latest version, I tried with different databases but the error keeps popping up. Tried searching internet, but either no answer to identical question or not related to my case. I suspect this has something to do with SQL Server (Express version) configuration but don't event know where to look.

Comment: Do you have any idea *which* Guid that message talks about? Are you importing a string field (supposedly containing a string version of a guid) into a real Guid? If so, at least one value is not a correct one (non-hex character, maybe?)

Comment: That's the thing, this message is so generic that I have no idea what it exactly refers to. I wanted to use Visual Studio as the tool to develop a database. I event tried with non-existing database (for Visual Studio to start a blank project and create database from script), but while publishing the same error message appeared.

Comment: I have even weirder problem. I can connect to a database, browse it's tables, stored procedures etc. but when I try to open a New Query to it, it shows me that GUID error. The error is instance specific - I can connect and query the databases from a different servers fine. So far no luck trying to figure out what the problem might actually be...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that will help you in your case, but I've finally found the reason behind my error.

```
System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithNoStyle(String guidString, GuidResult&amp; result)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult&amp; result)
   at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.ReliableSqlConnection.RetreiveSessionId()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.ReliableSqlConnection.OnConnectionStateChange(Object sender, StateChangeEventArgs e)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OnStateChange(StateChangeEventArgs stateChange)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.SetInnerConnectionEvent(DbConnectionInternal to)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.SetInnerConnectionEvent(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionInternal to)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.ReliableSqlConnection.&lt;OpenConnection&gt;b__0()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient
```

Now taking a look inside the `RetreiveSessionId` method, we can see a clear (in my oppinion) bug in the implementation:

```
using (System.Data.IDbCommand dbCommand = this.CreateReliableCommand())
{
    dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), CONTEXT_INFO())";
    object obj = dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    if (System.DBNull.Value != obj)
    {
        string g = (string)dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        this._azureSessionId = new System.Guid(g);
    }
}
```

That basically means, you should not have anything set in CONTEXT_INFO in your session (connection) to your SQL Server instance. In my case, we had a trigger that is run `FOR LOGON`, in which `SET CONTEXT_INFO` was being executed.

Once `SELECT CONTEXT_INFO()` was returning NULL, there was no more "*Guid should contain 32 digits (...)*" error to be seen.

The below query could be useful:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), context_info), * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

Hopefully that will help someone, as I did spend some time to figure this one out.