# cast to NVARCHAR(MAX) causes "chinese"/UTF encoded characters

Tags: sql-server

I am using code like this in my SELECT statement:

```
CAST(HASHBYTES(N'SHA1', Bla) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS hashed_bla
```

and end-up with "chinese"/UTF encoded characters in the ssms grid but also in upstream apps. Is there a way to change this? Does this have to do with the collation? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you cast a `varbinary` to `nvarchar`? Of course that means that there can be "strange" characters in the `varchar` then as the binary data can be anything not just a certain set of encoded characters. What did you expect?

Comment: Change your upstream apps so that they expect to receive an *arbitrary collection of bytes* rather than a string.

Comment: You can apply e.g. a BASE64 conversion on the bytes, which can then be decoded back to a byte array on the receiving end (if that is needed). Doing CAST to an NVARCHAR is definitely not the same as encoding it.

Comment: @stickybit - sorry but how else do I transform varbinary to a string? The target app requires JSON and all "columns" as strings. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be working as expected. Perhaps what you're really after is to keep the formatting of a `varbinary` but as an `nvarchar`? `SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(100),HASHBYTES('SHA1','B8187F0D-5DBA-4D43-95FC-CD5A009DB98C'),1);`

Comment: Well, if the application expects strings of "non special" characters then there is no way to pass it arbitrary binary data. Unless the application expects some encoding of the binary data like Base64 or something. Maybe tell something about that.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something here but if I do not CAST I see: 0x3EA3CF41136C528480BB287821BEBF14DD0ABE95 this is what I would like to send. i simply used HASH to anonymise some strings at our end.

Comment: @Larnu - you got it - sorry if that was not clear!

Comment: Why not just use `HASHBYTES(N'SHA1', Bla)` then? Why convert it to an `nvarchar` at all?

Comment: @Larnu my upstream ORM (Dapper) does not like the binary stuff so I figured I rather convert downstream - you convert does the trick so please post an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is working as expected. Take the following example:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1','B8187F0D-5DBA-4D43-95FC-CD5A009DB98C');
```

This returns the `varbinary` value `0xA04B9CB18A2DC4BC08B83FCCE48A0AF1A1390756`. You are then converting that value to an `nvarchar`, so get a result like `N'䮠놜ⶊ별레찿諤㦡嘇'` (on my collation). For an `varbinary` each 4 characters represents a single character. So, for the above `A04B` is the first character (which is `N'䮠'`).

It appears what you are after is an `varchar` representing a `varbinary` value (you don't need an `nvarchar` here, as there will be no unicode characters). To do so, you need to use `CONVERT` and a style code. For the example I gave above that would be:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100),HASHBYTES('SHA1','B8187F0D-5DBA-4D43-95FC-CD5A009DB98C'),1);
```

Which returns the `varchar` value `'0xA04B9CB18A2DC4BC08B83FCCE48A0AF1A1390756'`. If you don't want the `'0x'` at the start, use style code `2`, rather than `1`.

Comment: Now then why would Microsoft use `SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), CONTEXT_INFO())` in their implementation of `Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.ReliableSqlConnection.RetreiveSessionId()` before trying to create new GUID out of it...

Comment: With no citation I have no idea what you are asking about, @Nyuno .

Comment: There is nothing to be found about it in the internet. If you decompile ReliableSqlConnection class you then might find the part of the code I'm talking about (method is named RetreiveSessionId). To me it is a plain MSFT bug.

Comment: If you think there is a bug with a Microsoft product, @Nyuno , the comments under an answer on [so] is the completely wrong place to report it.#

Comment: I think you're missing my point. I'm not reporting a bug here, but merely being sarcastic about obvious mistake in the implementation after your great answer. Please check the problem I'm refering to and my answer to get the full picture: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776541/cannot-import-database-guid-should-contain-32-digits-with-4-dashes-error/69368317#69368317

In other words: your answer is great and just opened my eyes, actually pointing me in the right direction to solve a common problem I'm linking to above.

Comment: @Nyuno if you think my answer is wrong, explain that, don't try and beat around the bush and say there's something wrong with Microsoft's work (I have no control over that, I don't work for them). If you think you can post a better answer, post one here.

Comment: I don't think your answer is wrong. On the contrary - it is so elegant that it makes me wonder why would someone in MSFT rely on `CONTEXT_INFO` in the SSDT. Perhaps I'm not fluent in my English enough, for which I'm sorry in advance.